# Magento: checkout doesn't work in Internet Explorer 10 with Windows 8

Tags: magento, internet-explorer-10

My magento is working fine normally but in following environment it giving problem in checkout. (Cart remain empty)

Operating System : Windows 8
Browser : IE 10

I have also checkout http://demo.magentocommerce.com, but it is also not working.

Anyone has any idea ?

Comment: by "not working" you mean...?

Comment: what does your console say?

Comment: @Marius -  cart remain empty

Comment: @eyeonu - There is no error for script or any issue in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this bug please follow following steps :

1. Login to your magento administration
2. Go to System >> Configuration >> General >> Web >> Session Cookie Management >> Cookie Lifetime
3. Increase your cookie life time
4. Refresh cache

Now this bug will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks, still can't believe this actually worked! Have you also been able to figure out why this works?

Comment: Hmm, after the fist successful attempt, it failed again. I need to dive in deeper, I'm afraid.